# Parse id from two url formats in python

Tags: python, facebook, url

I'm new in python. I have two different url formats:

```
url_format_1 = 'https://www.facebook.com/facebook/posts/10151927580276729'
# and
url_format_2 = 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151496277356729&set=a.10150629589136729.412063.20531316728&type=1'
```

What I want is to get the `id`. On the first format is of course the `10151927580276729` and on the second `10151496277356729`.

I want to detect if there is the first or the second format used and proceed and get the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first format, you could use a simple `split()`. For the second format, I'd recommend using a regular expression.

For detecting which format you are dealing with, you could first try the regular expression. If that throws an exception, proceed and try to use `split()`.

```
import re

urls = [
    'https://www.facebook.com/facebook/posts/10151927580276729',
    'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151496277356729&set=a.10150629589136729.412063.20531316728&type=1',
    ]

for u in urls:
    try:
        print re.search(r'fbid=([0-9]+)', u).group(1)
    except:
        print u.split('/')[-1]
```

Output:

```
10151927580276729
10151496277356729
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But also how can I detect which format a random url has? Edit: Just saw the update. Thanks!